# Best way to build cross toolchains on Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, cross-compiling

I spent the last three weeks researching about crossdevelopment under Mac OS X. I want to achieve two separate results, but I believe they can be reached through the same path.
I want to

1. set up distcc to help my old Gentoo laptop using the iMac I recently got at home (OS X 10.6, 64 bit native) which I also use for iOS development, so Xcode 4 tools are already there;
2. develop my pet project which is an elf kernel for x86, x86_64, and arm (and I'll stop here as it's OT).

So, after a lot of that thinking thing we all do in these cases, I came up the idea that to reach the first goal I need to set up an i686-pc-linux-gnu toolchain (or is it i686-unknown-linux-gnu?) with all the appropriate versions (eg gcc-4.4) and make it callable by distcc. It seems like a reasonable task, but unfortunately there seem to be clearer tools and instructions to build toolchains for obscure archs like sparc or mips, and not a single reasonably updated resource on how to go for x86 the best way. Therefore, first question: is there anybody that succesfully build such a toolchain and feels like sharing the pain? :)

Second goal. My current workbench is made of Gentoo on an i686 laptop (yes, the same as the first goal) with all the regular development stuff, and I use QEMU to test it (its gdb integration is awesome). What I'd really like to do is to keep using the laptop while travelling (I do a lot of commuting) and continue to work and test on the iMac when I'm home (git is awesome in this respect). Hence, second question: is there anybody that have done something like this and wants to share?

I'd really appreciate any input. Seriously.

**EDIT** I know about MacPorts, crosstool, and crosstool-ng. I tried installing i386-elf-binutils 2.18 from MacPorts just to discover I have 2.20 in my laptop. Also I couldn't get gcc44 to produce i686-pc-linux-gnu elf objects, and using i386-elf-gcc is not an option as I need 4.4 and the packaged one is 4.3.

Answer (score 5):

This is no easy task, specially because you want to cross compile for so many different platforms.

The most used approach is to **run a Virtual Machine** with the desired OS (e.g. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/), [VMWare Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/overview.html)) and install your workbench tools to work from it. This is very often used because it's not complex to setup and it also make it easier to write, test and debug code for/from the target system.

Of course, if you search enough you'll find all sorts of hacks/tricks to setup a toolchain on Mac OS X and compile code for other architectures:

- One of these uses [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html), but that means that there is no official support for Mac OS X.
- Another one, also interesting, offers a *.dmg* package with the tools needed to [compile for Linux on MacOS X](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php?id=#compiling_for_linux_on_macos_x).

Comment: The VM approach would probably work for the distcc case (and at some point I actually considered it, then dumped it for a number of valid reasons), but I think it'd be a bit awkward for the other case, as I'd have to export my sources' directory on the net, mount it inside the VM, and launch the build process from the VM. Not exactly a smooth workflow.

Pre-built solutions often are not feasible, as with distcc you need the exact same minor version, ie 4.4.x and 4.5.y means kaboom.

Comment: I think it's worth to test the pre-built solution on this case. Another approach is building the tools yourself: http://www.nongnu.org/thug/cross.html

Comment: I tried that, and failed shortly after. Then I tried crosstool-ng which seems to be working fine, though it's causing a huge amount of frustration and bafflement. It's probably not its fault but Mac OS X's, and its being a BSD with a number of unexplicable assumptions like a case-insensitive filesystem. Still so far it seems the most promising way.

Comment: Both are unfeasible. Buildroot seems to not go very well with SL/Lion, and the other one doesn't offer gcc-4.4 which is the version I need. Thanks for the hints, though.

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned Gentoo, so I think you should take a look at [Gentoo Prefix](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/). Gentoo Prefix lets you install a small Gentoo system in a user defined directory (= prefix). From there, you may start a shell which lets you use portage (= Gentoo's package system) which should enable you to install the necessary tools.

I do not know in what shape Prefix on OS X today is, but I was able to install it on a friend's MacBook a year or so ago. If you are interested, I can give further details about the [installation process](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/gentoo-alt/prefix/bootstrap-macos.xml) which can be a bit tricky.

Comment: I already tried Prefix, unfortunately it installs a native toolchain (specifically one which targets x86_64-apple-darwin10). There's a fine tool in Gentoo called crossdev but it fails to emerge in Prefix.

Comment: Let me have a look at the build.log.