# Reading conflicting notes on Cross Compiling

Tags: cross-compiling

1)In general, you must have a complete cross environment in order to do the build. This normally means a cross compiler, cross assembler, and so forth, as well as libraries and 
include files for the host system and target system.

2) Cross compiling from OS X

```
port install arm-none-eabi-gcc
port install arm-none-eabi-binutils

export CCPREFIX=/opt/local/bin/arm-none-eabi-
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
```

1 and 2 seems to be conflicting. 1 says host and target system must have same libraries and include files but 2 says it's OK to compile ARM code from MAc system and which they do not share same libraries.

So what gives? which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? I don't know, if it runs under OS X, but you can still create a Linux VM and use BR from there.

BR will take care of toolchain and provides lots of packages like Qt, Gtk, Boost etc.

Also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396165/best-way-to-build-cross-toolchains-on-mac-os-x).